# How to test Formik Fields with Enzyme and Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, formik

I want to test if specific types of input fields are render, with Enzyme. I am using Formik, for my forms. But every time I am writing a test for that specific use case, I get this weird object error back from enzyme.

```
    Expected value to have length:
      1
    Received:
      {Symbol(enzyme.__root__): {Symbol(enzyme.__root__): [Circular], Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): <WithFormik(AddEditUser) />, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render":
 [Function render], "simulateError": [Function simulateError], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount": [Function unmount]}, Symbol(enzyme.__node__): {"instance": null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "class", "props": {"displayName":
 "AddEditUser", "enableReinitialize": false, "handleSubmit": [Function handleSubmit], "initialValues": {"confirmPassword": "", "email": "", "group": "", "password": "", "username": ""}, "isInitialValid": false, "onSubmit": [Function anonymous], 
"render": [Function anonymous], "validate": undefined, "validateOnBlur": true, "validateOnChange": true, "validationSchema": [Function anonymous]}, "ref": null, "rendered": null, "type": [Function Formik]}, Symbol(enzyme.__nodes__): [{"instance"
: null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "class", "props": {"displayName": "AddEditUser", "enableReinitialize": false, "handleSubmit": [Function handleSubmit], "initialValues": {"confirmPassword": "", "email": "", "group": "", "password": "", "user
name": ""}, "isInitialValid": false, "onSubmit": [Function anonymous], "render": [Function anonymous], "validate": undefined, "validateOnBlur": true, "validateOnChange": true, "validationSchema": [Function anonymous]}, "ref": null, "rendered": n
ull, "type": [Function Formik]}], Symbol(enzyme.__options__): {"adapter": {"options": {"enableComponentDidUpdateOnSetState": true, "lifecycles": {"componentDidUpdate": {"onSetState": true}, "getDerivedStateFromProps": true, "getSnapshotBeforeUpd
ate": true, "setState": {"skipsComponentDidUpdateOnNullish": true}}}}}}, Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): null, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render": [Function render], 
"simulateError": [Function simulateError], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount": [Function unmount]}, Symbol(enzyme.__node__): undefined, Symbol(enzyme.__nodes__): [], Symbol(enzyme.__options__): {"adapter": {"options": {"enableC
omponentDidUpdateOnSetState": true, "lifecycles": {"componentDidUpdate": {"onSetState": true}, "getDerivedStateFromProps": true, "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate": true, "setState": {"skipsComponentDidUpdateOnNullish": true}}}}}, Symbol(enzyme.__rootNod
es__): [{"instance": null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "class", "props": {"displayName": "AddEditUser", "enableReinitialize": false, "handleSubmit": [Function handleSubmit], "initialValues": {"confirmPassword": "", "email": "", "group": "", "p
assword": "", "username": ""}, "isInitialValid": false, "onSubmit": [Function anonymous], "render": [Function anonymous], "validate": undefined, "validateOnBlur": true, "validateOnChange": true, "validationSchema": [Function anonymous]}, "ref": 
null, "rendered": null, "type": [Function Formik]}]}
    received.length:
      0
```

Here is my tests:

```
  it('Expects to have 1 text field in the form', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<AddEditUser />);
    const text = wrapper.find('text');
    expect(text).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

What it says basically, is that it looks for text fields and get back 0, along with the above error.

Here is my Component:

```
<Fragment>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="col-7">
            <div className="my-3">
              <label>
                <span className="font-weight-bold">Username</span>
                <span className="text-danger">*</span>
              </label>
              <Field
                className={classNames('form-control', {
                  'is-invalid': errors.username && touched.username
                })}
                placeholder="Username (Required)"
                name="username"
                type="text"
              />
              {errors.username && touched.username ? (
                <div className="text-danger">{errors.username}</div>
              ) : null}
            </div>
         </Form>
</Fragment>
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here? According to the documentation examples that should be it. Is Formik fields, a special case. Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a full component code ?

Answer (score 2):

`wrapper.find('text')` is looking for a `text` element, not an input of type text.

Formik's `Field` component defaults to an `input` element ([source](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field))

Try `wrapper.find('input')`

Or Use the class: `wrapper.find('.form-control')`